# Dock similar to alarm screen (horizontalscroll with animation)

Tags: android, animation, screen, alarm, dock

I really need implement a nice dock with horizontal scroll but using animation.

I looking for something similar to this:

[image]

Could you give me a idea how I can implement this dock? Is it native? Where I can find projects(source code) with a similar docks?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a HTC-Phone, right? This piece of the ui is part of the whole "HTC Sense UI". So no, it is not a native ui element from android and you have to implement it on your own.

Or you will find a similar example code on the internet :) I saw that, but don´t remember where.

Comment: Thanks for you opinion. It is true, it is a component of HTC Sense API. I found how I can implement it using the HTC Sense API but this component only will work in HTC devices. The link is this:   [link] http://htcdev.com/devcenter/common-controls/sample-code   .I am looking for something like this but in open source. I think it is a really nice component.

Comment: The name of this component is TabPlus